# Proof of equivalency in disjoint sets.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove, If A, B, C, and D are sets with |A|=|B| and |C|=|D| and if A and C are disjoint and B and D are disjoint, then |A ∪ C|= |B ∪ D|.

Would I start this proof using the definition of disjoint sets with A and C? Also would this turn into a proof by contradiction?

Comment: What does $\approx$ mean here?

Comment: equivalent, meaning the sets have the same cardinality

Comment: Oh okay. It's best to write that as $|A|=|B|$ and $|C|=|D|$ since $|\cdot|$ is the conventional notation for the cardinality of a set.

Comment: Thank you, first time user.

Comment: I understand. I am answering now below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that $|A\cup C|=|B\cup D|$. Since $|A|=|B|$ and $|C|=|D|$, there are bijections $g:A\to B$ and $h:C\to D$.

Define $f:A\cup C\to B\cup D$ as follows:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
g(x)&\text{if}&x\in A\\
h(x)&\text{if}&x\in C
\end{cases}.
$$

Then, $f$ is a bijection since $A\cap C=B\cap D=\emptyset$.

Comment: I was way over thinking this one, I got too caught up in the definition of disjoint. I couldn't connect the bijection between the functions. Thank you huge help in simplifying the answer I had!